# Is autofilling with sms code on iOS possible?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Is autofill sms code on iOS possible?
Hello, I am doing a research about autofilling fields with code received via sms.
With flutter package for android it works - when sms comes fields on screen automatically fill with it.
Fot iOS I see the code shows above the keyboard.

Is it possible to make it fill fields just like on android? Without need to show keyborad and press the code from it?

Comment: Read the documentation of types of UITextField, something like “onetime password”. Modifies the keyboard so when an SMS arrives while you could enter the number it’s taken from the SMS.

Answer (score 1):

SMS autofill on iOS is done by iOS. Apps aren't involved. They can't see an incoming SMS and they don't see the code shown above the keyboard. It's not "autofill" in that it doesn't automatically type the number. The user must confirm it by tapping the code.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that no app can have access to sms code on ios?

Comment: iOS apps are not allowed to read user's text messages

Comment: Obviously you can’t. Think about privacy. I don’t want any app be able to access my messages. It only happens in very obvious situations and only when the user agrees.

Comment: @gnasher729
Why would I think of privacy when for android there are signatures in sms or there could be an option to give an app access to one number belonging to app provider?

Comment: @helloitme4 the designated SMS number of the app provider may change over the time. It's true, there's a mechanism on Android to check for an Authentication signature at the end of OTP messages, but that doesn't say that the user can ultimately trust the app provider that his messages won't be read by the app provider for an undesired level. So, iOS users worry about there privacy I think!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, ios judges the best-suited number out of the sms, which it thinks is an OTP, and it's correct. Sometimes it fails, usually with money transaction via credit card, or if the OTP is not six digit.